How to get rid of Public IPv4s on aws
We have several websites running on aws, and recently a new invoice item has been added, namely  Public IPv4 Addresses with a charge of $0.005 / hour.
We perfectly understand that public IPv4 addresses are a scarce resource and we are absolutely ready to get rid of those that we don't need.
But, we cannot find a way on how to do that.
I found this recent post from aws (April 25), which seems to bring a solution to the problem:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/04/removing-adding-auto-assigned-public-ipv4-address/
However, in 'Network Interfaces' console, I cant find where this would happen.

There's no single "button" or anything like that in the AWS console to do this. This is not a quick and easy fix. You will have to change your VPC to enable IPV6 addresses, and redeploy your EC2 instances with IPV6 enabled, and IPV4 disabled. As your question is written, without any actual details as to what AWS support suggested, or what you tried, it sounds more like a complaint about AWS support than anything, which is off-topic for this site.

Here's an AWS blog post detailing what you need to do: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-ipv6-only-subnets-and-ec2-instances/

What was a "surprising recommendation" that AWS support gave you?

for example:
The concerned eni-05808e3d3773...  is associated with instance i-0b6d0b2f3d9a0..... Therefore, once this instance is deleted, the ENI will be deleted as well

So Amazon support told you what to do - get rid of things that have IP's.  You're looking at about $14/month for what you are showing.  Azure and GCP have similar pricing.

Deleting an instance as a valid recommendation??? It is not about the price, 14 $ is not the end of the world, but this thing about charging clients without giving possibility to delete it when not needed is just really bad.

Yes, deleting an instance is a valid recommendation.  If you need an instance setup differently than it's currently setup, it's fairly common to delete the existing one and redeploy with the changed config.

If you are actively using these instances and IP addresses, at $3.60/month (0.005x24x30) per IP address it's probably not worth spending your time on trying to avoid this cost. It's equivalent to the amount you get paid during a lunch break. The good thing about these charges is that it's making people think more about IPv6, which is what the world needs so we can move on from IPv4.

No, we don't need these additional IP. We only want to delete them. But it looks like that achieving this is only possible by deleting and recreating the instance, which means service disruption. Do I see this correctly?
